# Tool/framework for automated web app testing in Google Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, testing, browser

Is an opensource/commercial tool/framework, available for automated web app testing in Google Chrome browser on Windows XP / Vista? ( An alpha/beta Tool is also OK)

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Selenium supports Chrome pretty much out of the box because it works by injecting javascript in the web page. http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/

Webdriver has an early version of Chrome driver. http://code.google.com/p/webdriver/

Both are open source and works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tool called QA Agent (http://qaagent.com). This is a web based IDE where you can develop your tests using jQuery and javascript. Currently it supports only Chrome so may be it will be a good choice for you. And of course it is free.

Comment: This appears to have gone away now (link doesn't resolve).

Answer (score -1):

For those who are not developers you could try [FRET](https://www.frontendtest.org) for automated web testing with Chrome. It's still in beta and even though it states that no programming is needed a basic understanding of HTML / CSS etc. is recommended.