# VBScript to Launch a website login

Tags: vbscript

I found this script online, I edited most of it.

It is able to enter username, and password on its down but it is not able to click login.

please help me fix
**Here is login forum.**

```
http://desistream.tv/en/index.shtml
```

**Here is Script** currently it is in IE but I will need to change it open in Google Chrome.

```
WScript.Quit Main

Function Main
  Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "http://desistream.tv/en/index.shtml"
  Wait IE
  With IE.Document
    .getElementByID("login_username").value = "myusername"
    .getElementByID("login_password").value = "mypassword"
    .getElementByID("form").submit
  End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
End Sub

Sub IE_OnQuit
  On Error Resume Next
  WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "IE closed before script finished."
  WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is...

```
Call Main

Function Main
    Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "http://desistream.tv/en/index.shtml"
    Wait IE
    With IE.Document
        .getElementByID("username").value = "myusername"
        .getElementByID("pass").value = "mypassword"
        .getElementsByName("frmLogin")(0).Submit
    End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I add condition if account is already logged in? because it is prompting error.

Comment: Glad to see that I not forget everything as my last web scripting was about 10 years ago :)
The site rules not allow multiple questions in one topic, so you can open new topic if you like, and probably will get better reply, but my short reply is - just find an html element that's available on that page only when you logged-in and check for existence of that element, and to start login only if needs.

Comment: As for doing so in Google Chrome, you can't without automation extensions. See this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87911/tool-framework-for-automated-web-app-testing-in-google-chrome-browser), or just google for "google chrome browser automation".

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the page source, you'll see that the actual `<form>` tag is called `frmLogin`, not `login`.

Comment: Thanks alot, I looked at div id forum, not form name, Thanks alot.

Comment: I have question, how can I make it not prompt error, if account is already logged in ? Thanks