# Page refresh after few seconds with entering username and password

Tags: loops, vbscript, page-refresh

I need a vbscript which should open a page in IE, enter username and password, then keep on refreshing the page after few seconds.  I have no idea of vbscript, but here is what I found after searching, it keeps on refreshing the page. doesnt seem to work, keeps on giving me error, object required. The username and password does have a value, I have just omitted it here. The error just comes up before the username could be entered.

```
Call Main

Function Main
  Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "URL"
  Wait IE
  With IE.Document
    .getElementsByName("LoginName")(0).value = ""
    .getElementsByName("Password")(0).value = ""
    .getElementsByTagName("a")(0).click
  End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
```

Below is the error

[image]

Comment: What error, and on which line exactly?

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I just added the error screenshot, please take a look.

Comment: Check if there actually is a tag with a name attribute `LoginName` on that page.

Comment: Yes, there is, in case you would like to take a look, the url is also given in the post

Comment: The page requires both JavaScript and a plugin. I think I'll pass on that.

Comment: Hmm..well I have this another post which is doing same stuff, but uses ID to fetch element - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221907/vbscript-to-launch-a-website-login?rq=1