# Script - open a web page, enter credentials and keep on refreshing after few seconds

Tags: javascript, vbscript, refresh

I have a requirement where I have to open a web page from my desktop, enter the username and password and once its logged in, I want to be able to refresh that page after few seconds.
I tried this with vbscript, but facing some issue, not able to solve. Just wanted to check if this can be done with javascript as well, if yes, then how?

vbscript -[Page refresh after few seconds with entering username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496148/page-refresh-after-few-seconds-with-entering-username-and-password)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jQuery to create a timer, and in the timer code, refresh the page. That might be the easiest option.

See [here for info on how to setup a timer](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/). You could write something like:

```
var timer = $.timer(function() {
    location.reload(); // Reload the page
});

timer.set({ time : 5000, autostart : true });
```

If you only want this to work when the user is logged in, then you could have a server-side guard around this statement. Eg, for something with ASP/VBScript:

```
<% if (UserIsLoggedIn) then %>
// Javascript code here
<% end if %>
```

Comment: I can not make changes in the page code directly, its served from external server.